# prove that $\overrightarrow{F(t)} = (\cos t)\hat{a} + (\sin t)\hat{b}$ is a unit circle

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, circles

Let $\hat{a},\hat{b} \in \mathbb{R^3}$ be two perpendicular unit vectors. If $\overrightarrow{F(t)} = (\cos t)\hat{a} + (\sin t)\hat{b}$ with $t \in [0 ,2\pi]$. How can I prove that this vector function is a unit circle in $\mathbb{R^3}$? I tried a to define a plane in $U$ such that $\hat{a},\hat{b} \in U$ and then define a basis for every point in that plane as $\beta = \{\hat{a},\hat{b},\hat{a} \times \hat{b} \}$ and writing $\overrightarrow{F}$ in terms of that basis. But this things I learned in Linear Algebra and this Is a Calculus II class, I'm no allowed to use things from other classes.

Comment: Whats the definition of inner product here ?\

Comment: For example $\sin(nx),\cos(mx)$ are orependicular in $[0,2\pi]$ by $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(nx)\cos(mx)dx$

Comment: @Khosrotash The regular Dot product.

Comment: Hint :$\hat{a}\bot \hat{a}\times \hat{b}\to \hat{a}.(\hat{a}\times \hat{b})=0\\
\hat{b}\bot \hat{a}\times \hat{b}\to \hat{b}.(\hat{a}\times \hat{b})=0\\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
\begin{align*}
\lvert \mathbf{F}(t) \rvert^2 &= \mathbf{F}(t) \cdot \mathbf{F}(t) = \cos^2 t \; \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a} + 2 \cos t \sin t \; \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} + \sin^2t \;\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b} \\
&= \cos^2t + \sin^2t \\
&= 1
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a} = 1$ and similarly for $\mathbf{b}$ since they are unit vectors, and $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = 0$ since they are perpendicular.

So $\mathbf{F}(t)$ always lies *on* the unit circle. Note also that
$$\mathbf{F}(t) \cdot \mathbf{a} = \cos t, \quad \mathbf{F}(t) \cdot \mathbf{b} = \sin t$$
so, we see that the projections of $\mathbf{F}(t)$ onto the perpendicular directions $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ vary from $-1$ to $1$, which (perhaps by drawing a diagram with $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ as axes in the centre of a circle) suffices to conclude that every point on the circle is visited by $\mathbf{F}(t)$.

---

As you've found, really $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are a good basis for your subspace in which this defines a unit circle, since with respect to that basis, your components are $(\cos t, \sin t)$.

Comment: But any curve in $ \textbf{ r}(t)$ the unit sphere have that $|\textbf{ r}(t)| = 1$. So that is not sufficient. I need to show as well that all the ponts in $\textbf{F}(t) \in U$ where $U$ is the plane deffined by $ \mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. But that I know how to do. Thanks

Comment: The part of my answer with $\mathbf{F}(t) \cdot \mathbf{a}$ and similarly with $\mathbf{b}$ was intended to address this point.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry then. Thank you